# Gradle sync failed: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

I have updated my Android Studio from 2.x to 3.x. At first it showed gradle sync failed, then I fixed it somehow with the help of Stack Overflow. In that process I updated gradle. It fixed for some time later by following the steps in the Stack Overflow post. I deleted one file in gradle, now this is came out:

> Gradle sync failed: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found

### Please any one tell me how to fix it.

here is the file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.demoandroid.udacitybdcard"
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 25
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-
rules.pro'
}
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'}
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle and try to explain better your issue.

Comment: can you post the entire build.gradle file instead of just the error. There is not much to help with when only given an error